# $queryResult = new WP_Query( $args ) unknown error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

since I am totally new to php i struggle with one custom function, problem is in line $queryResult = new WP_Query( $args ); since when I comment it out with the rest of function, everything works. However when it is there, page will show me no results for reservation which is strange

so function here

```
function getListOfUsersOnLesson($lesson_id) {

    $result = '... nikto nie je prihlásený';

    $args = array (
            'post_type' => 'rsg_reservations',
            'pagination' => false,
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'meta_key' => '_rsg_reservation_lesson_id',
            'meta_value' => $lesson_id,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $result = '';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $user_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_rsg_reservation_user_id', true );
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            $user_email = $user_info->user_email;
            $username = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true ).' '.get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );

            $erroclass = '';
            if(reservationIsValid($lesson_id, $user_id)) $erroclass = '';
            else $erroclass = 'erroruser';

            $result.= '<div class="row">';
            $result.= '<div class="col-md-4 '.$erroclass.'">'.$username.'</div>';
            $result.= '<div class="col-md-6 '.$erroclass.'">'.$user_email.'</div>';
            $result.= '<div class="col-md-2"></div>';
            $result.= '</div>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $result;

}
```

When NOT commented out
 [image: When NOT commented out]

When commented out, desired state
[image: When commented out, desired state]

whole code is called by another method in a separate php file

```
$lesson_user_list = '';
            if(is_super_admin()) {
                $lesson_user_list = getListOfUsersOnLesson($lesson_id);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, that puece with error class seems to be a problem

Answer (score 1):

You may be you mess with query variable ( $queryResult and $query )

```
if ( $queryResult->have_posts() ) {
        $result = '';
        while ( $queryResult->have_posts() ) {
            $queryResult->the_post();
```

Comment: Copy paste error, actually I fixed that but no changes

Comment: everything seem correct. if You create custom post type "rsg_reservations" then may be problem in your $lesson_id. just check, is your $lesson_id contain your desire value? or your meta_key is correct as you declare?

Answer (score 0):

You execute a new WP_Query and loading it into `$queryResult`, but then do not use it (your code uses `$query`, which isn't defined / doesn't contain anything).

Change your code as follows:

```
// You are loading results into $queryResult here
$queryResult = new WP_Query( $args );
// below switched FROM $query->have_posts() TO $queryResult->have_posts()
if ( $queryResult->have_posts() ) {
    $result = '';
    // switch to $queryResult->have_posts()
    while ( $queryResult->have_posts() ) {
        // switch to $queryResult->the_post()
        $queryResult->the_post();
        // ... the rest of your code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: that was my mistake, i forgot to change it, but anyway after I change it, it has same result